# School assignment - What is the mean and standard deviation of the fraction of occupied subway seats?

Tags: statistics, python

There is a subway car with  adjacent seats in a row. People walk into the subway and choose a random available seat (drawn uniformly). The only constraint on seat availability is that they do not like to sit next to one another so there is always (at least) one empty seat between any two individuals. This process continues until all available seats are taken.

What is the mean and standard deviation of the fraction of occupied seats (when the process is complete) for different values of , try  = 25, 100, and 1000.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @PseudoLooped, here is the link to the c code https://gist.github.com/wenhuizhang/d5c7a4601bc0e5cae696/629c7a17c56d31c7ad03661be3ec4446995ac029. unfortunately I am not trained in C, do u have any idea how to convert the language to python and also explain the idea to the solution? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: That would be a much better question for StackOverflow in terms of explaining/understanding code, what I was more asking is what have you tried/attempted to calculate the mean and standard deviation of the proposed problem

Comment: @PseudoLooped, I see. TBH I'm really new to statistics so I don't even understand what the question is asking. I'm hoping you can explain the concept behind the question. Once I have a context then I can start building the python code. Do u have any idea what the question is asking?

Comment: My guess is: $for\:the\:kth\:person\:the\:ratio\:of\:filled\:seats\:to\:vacant\:seats\:is:\:f\left(k\right)=\frac{\left(\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)-\left(k-1\right)\right)}{n}$